# Finding equilibrium points for the system $y'=Ay$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a matrix $A= \begin{pmatrix} 8 & 4 \\ -10 & -5 \end{pmatrix}$, I am supposed to find all of the equilibrium points for the system $y'=Ay$

I find the eigenvalues are 0 and -3, and the corresponding eigenvectors $(1,-2)^T$ and $(4,-5)^T$

I am not sure what equilibrium points they want, are we particularly choosing $\lambda=0$?

Comment: Well, what *is* an equilibrium point?

Comment: nullspace of $Ay=0$?

Comment: probably when $y' = 0$ i.e. $Ay=0$. This justifies the choice of $\lambda=0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y_0$ is an equilibrium point $ \iff Ay_0=0 \iff y_0= t (1,-2)^T$ for some $t \in \mathbb R.$